# Where-Object not finding match but it should

Tags: powershell, where-object

I have Code that imports and excel spreadsheet like this, and I've used this for other excel files fine:

```
$importedExcel = Import-Excel -Path $errorCodeListFilePath -StartRow $startRow
return $importedExcel
```

The returned map is stored like this:

```
[Object[178]]
...
[2]:
Contents:"some string"
ErrorCode Upper: 12
ErrorCode Lower: "3A"
Error Item: "some more info"
Recovery: "important recovery info"
Recovery Method Info: "A12"
...
```

Where sometimes ErrorCode Upper is a string and sometimes it's a number, and same for Lower.

```
$deviceErrDescMap = Process_ErrorDescMap -errorCodeListFilePath $errorCodeListFile
```

And the data looks as expected, shown above (excel returned in code snippet above).

For this excel file, I think it's confused because some data is an int and some is a string, so I think my where-object is missing the match. For this one, I had to split a hex number into the first two and second two digits, because the spreadsheet splits them across two columns.

```
                  $sdkNum = "0x123A"
                  $sdkNumArr = @($sdkNum -split 'x') 
                  $sdkNumArr1 =  $sdkNumArr[1] -split ''
                  $sdkNumUpper = "$($sdkNumArr1[1])$($sdkNumArr1[2])" #12 ..naming is counter-intuitive
                  $sdkNumLower = "$($sdkNumArr1[3])$($sdkNumArr1[4])" #3A
                  $deviceErrDescRow = $deviceErrDescMap | Where-Object {([string]'ErrorCode Upper' -eq $sdkNumUpper)} #returns no results
```

When I hover over $sdkNumUpper" I see "12", so it looks like a string.  Can't I cast the spreadsheet/map content to string like I'm showing? I'm having trouble finding this info with an internet search.  But something must be wrong with my Where-Object, because even though I see the row is there, it's returning null for $deviceErrDescRow.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to use the `-NoNumberConversion 'ErrorCode Upper'` parameter with `Export-Excel` when exporting the file so that when you import it it's interpreted as a string and not a number

Comment: I don't export the spreadsheet.  It's just a file in my directory.

Comment: I tried selecting both rows of the spreadsheet and changing the format to text and it's still not getting the match with where-object when I run the script

Comment: I tried forcing the spreadsheet row to a string with a single quote in front of the number, and removed [string] from my where-object, and it's still not matching the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the syntax of your `Where-Object` call:

> `... | Where-Object {([string]'ErrorCode Upper' -eq $sdkNumUpper)}`

You're comparing the *string literal* `'ErrorCode Upper'` to `$sdkNumUpper`, not the *value of the `.ErrorCode Upper` property*.

If you're using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) with a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), you need to refer to the input object at hand via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)

```sh
... | Where-Object { $sdkNumUpper -eq $_.'ErrorCode Upper' }
```

Note that by placing the string-valued `$sdkNumUpper` on the *LHS*, the property value on the RHS is implicitly converted to a string too, if needed.

---

By contrast, when you use the syntactically easier [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax), the property access is always the LHS, and only the property *name* must be specified, which is *implicitly* applied  to the input object object at hand (in other words: application to `$_` is implied).

```sh
# Note: 'ErrorCode Upper' binds to parameter -Property, $sdkNumUpper to -Value
# Equivalent to:
#   ... | Where-Object { $_.'ErrorCode Upper' -eq $sdkNumUpper }
... | Where-Object 'ErrorCode Upper' -eq $sdkNumUpper
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why this worked for all the other import-excel where-object statements but this one!   Is it just because I'm using {} this time?

Comment: @Michele, yes; in short: if you transition from simplified syntax to using a script block, you must place `$_.` before the property name.